# Python SocketServer.TCPServer errno 10054

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I'm running a python server using the socketserver module in python 2.7. OmniPeek packet analysis tool shows the TCP handshake completes, 
but the server immediately sends a reset packet killing the connection.

Simplified server code which shows the problem is:

```
from threading import Lock, Thread, Condition
import SocketServer
import socket
import sys
import time


class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, state, *args, **keys):

        try:
            state['lock'].acquire()
            state['client_count'] += 1
        finally:
            state['lock'].release()

        self.state = state
        SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **keys)

    def handle(self):
        self.state['lock'].acquire()
        count = self.state['client_count']
        self.state['lock'].release()

        while True:
            try:
                self.state['lock'].acquire()
                running = self.state['running']
                self.state['lock'].release()
                if not running:
                    break;

                time.sleep(1)   # do some work

            except Exception as msg:
                print msg

        print "ThreadedTCPRequestHandler shutting down..."


class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass


def handler_factory(state):
    def createHandler(*args, **keys):
        return ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(state, *args, **keys)
    return createHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Lock()
    cv = Condition(lock)
    state = {'running': True, 'client_count': 0, 'lock': lock, 'cv': cv}

    server = ThreadedTCPServer(('localhost', 12345), handler_factory(state))
    server_thread = Thread(target=server.serve_forever)   
    server_thread.daemon = True  
    server_thread.start()
    print "Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name

    # wait for a client to connect
    cv.acquire()
    while state['client_count'] == 0 and state['running']:
        cv.wait(1.0)
        # print msg
    cv.release()  

    # substitute real work here...
    time.sleep(5)

    lock.acquire()
    state['running'] = False
    lock.release()
    server.shutdown()
```

and the client code:

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print 'ip: {}  port {}'.format('10.4.2.54', 12345)
        client.connect(('10.4.2.54', 12345))

        while True:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break;

            print 'data: {}'.format(data)

        client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        client.close()
    except Exception as msg:
        print msg
```

The server code is based off python 2.7 docs serversocket Mixin example, and seems pretty straightforward, but...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - red herring. The problem is only occurring under VM when server is running under guest and client is running under host. TCP reset packet never sent when both client and server are running either on host or guest

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your expected behaviour is but if you make a couple of changes, you'll be able to see that it can work

replace your handle method

```
def handle(self):
    while True:
        try:
            data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            if len(data) != 0:
                print data

            time.sleep(1)   # do some work
            self.request.send('test data')
        except Exception as msg:
            print msg
            break

    print "ThreadedTCPRequestHandler shutting down..."
```

and client(inside main):

```
try:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'ip: {}  port {}'.format('localhost', 1232)
    client.connect(('localhost', 1232))
    client.send('test')
    n = 0
    while True:
        data = client.recv(4096)
        if len(data) != 0:
          print 'data: {}'.format(data)

        time.sleep(1)
        n += 1
        client.send('keep-alive' + str(n) + '\n')
        print 'here'

    client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    client.close()
except Exception as msg:
    print msg
```

I just modded it to send stuff and print stuff.  But it doesn't crash.
I think there is an issue with your self.state['lock'].acquire() and release() calls. I took out the 'running' check as it's not really used except at the end of the server code.
Also, without any action, sockets will time out.

Once again, I'm not claiming to have 'fixed' your problem...and I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for...just helping you brainstorm!

Comment: thanks for posting. I took out all the send/recv code for brevity before posting, but problem is related to VM